# Facing permission error while deploying package using salesforce ant migration tool

Tags: deployment, salesforce, force.com

I am facing the following error while trying to deploy code package using ant migration tool to a new org. [error while deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgTPX.png)
It is saying you do not have permission to insert the field.

I checked and the permissions on the field are already given on the profile I am deploying. [field permission on profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byeNh.png). I am not sure how can I resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

is the field a lookup/master-detail? If it is - you'll need at least "Read" right on the object being looked up.

Comment: Yes, it is a lookup field. I checked the permission on the object being looked up and it's already given.

Comment: Is it from managed package? Does your user have licence assigned to use Financial Force?